# How do I log commits introduced from a 'git merge' before resolving and committing?

Tags: git, merge

Imagine the following state of a repository:

```
feature        *-----*
              /
master   *---*---*---*
```

I `clone` and then checkout `master` onto my machine.

I then `merge` the `feature` branch and there are conflicts.

Performing a `git log --graph` only shows commits up to my `HEAD` and will exclude divergent commits from the `feature` branch. In other words, the head node in the graph always converges from the previous commits.

How do I get a view that includes the divergent commits introduced from the `merge` *before* resolving and committing them?

Comment: The problem was that `git log --all` was not displaying my commits in chronological order, at least not entirely. I had to to scroll down further to see the divergent `feature` commit, which was not in chronological order with the commits from `master`. IntelliJ shows them in order when viewing a log of all branches: I imagine `git log` does this due to ascii rendering restrictions in some circumstances, to constrain the width of the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @knittl points out, you don't have a merge commit, so git sees only `master` by default.  If you want to see the commits on `feature` too, list what you want logs for.  For this, you'll want either

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline   master...feature
```

or

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline   master..feature
```

See [*gitrevisions*](https://www.google.com/search?q=git%20help%20revisions&oq=git%20help%20revisions&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.7958j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) for all the ways to spell various sets of commits.

---

<sup>As an aside, make yourself an alias for those log options, mine's `lgdo`:

   `git config alias.lgdo log --graph --decorate --oneline`

and from then on, `git lgdo` works a treat.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

When `git merge` conflicts, then it will not create a new commit. You first have to resolve the commits and then run `git commit` manually. Afterwards you can see both parents of the commit. `git show $merge_commit` will show you the conflict resolution (differences that are in neither of the parents)